# Conditional order by clause

Tags: oracle, join, sql-order-by, union

Below query returning error. Help me under the error and a way to achieve the conditional order by. I am trying to order by grade and name when grade >=8 and grade and marks when grade <8.

```
SELECT
    name, grade, marks
FROM
    students, grades
WHERE
    min_mark <= marks
    AND   marks <= max_mark
    AND   marks >= 70
UNION
SELECT
    TO_CHAR('NULL') AS name, grade, marks
FROM
    students, grades
WHERE
    min_mark <= marks
    AND   marks <= max_mark
    AND   marks <= 69
order by grade desc,(case when grade >= 8 
                     then  name 
                     when grade < 8 
                     then marks  
                     end );
```

> ERROR:
>   order by grade desc,(case when grade >= 8
>   *
>   ERROR at line 18:
>   ORA-01785: ORDER BY item must be the number of a SELECT-list expression

Comment: Tried but not working. The error persists.

Comment: Try `case when grade >= 8 then name else marks end`. Does the original SQL contain the asterisks ** ?  It should not.

Comment: It also shouldn't have a string value in one branch and a number in the other; and converting marks to a string for this wouldn't make sense. Neither does `TO_CHAR('NULL')` though really; is that supposed to be `cast(null as varchar2(20))` or something?

Comment: At first glance, I thought it is just error with scoping of order by, but after checking again it seems you have several issues with your query. Tell us what output exactly you want to see with sample data in text format.

Comment: Also show us the error message, please.

Comment: Appears to be an issue with the `8` in the case statement and oracle thinking you are referencing a column by ordinal when there aren't `8` columns in the select list.

Comment: The error message is shown at the bottom of the question. And it isn't the 8, you get the same error if you change both of those to 1.

Comment: Try this : `case when grade >= 8 
                     then  'NULL' 
                     when grade < 8 
                     then marks  
                     end`

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes tried the suggestion. The error persists.

Comment: @AlexPoole If I remove the case from order by clause the query is running fine. I don't think having a number and string in order by would lead to an error. Thanks for your suggestion on TO_CHAR('NULL'), will update the query.

Comment: @KaushikNayak I am trying to pull grades based on marks for a student. If grade>= 8 then result should be sorted based on grade in desc, names in alphabetic order, or else grade in desc, marks in asc.

Comment: @DhavalShah, that would entirely miss my requirement, Sure will give it a try. Thanks

Comment: @ShanmukhaReddy - if you remove the case expression you don't hit the bug (see my answer!). You can order by both string and  number expressions; you get an error if you mix them *within* a case expression (again, I referred to that inmy answer).

Comment: Thanks, @AlexPoole. But how do I hit my requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be bug 5695629, which seems to have been raised against 10g and doesn't seem to have been fixed yet (as of 12cR2; I don't have 18 to play with yet), which is unusual.

You can avoid it by wrapping the query in an outer select before ordering:

```
select name, grade, marks
from
(
    SELECT
        name, grade, marks
    FROM
        students, grades
    WHERE
        min_mark <= marks
        AND   marks <= max_mark
        AND   marks >= 70
    UNION
    SELECT
        TO_CHAR('NULL') AS name, grade, marks
    FROM
        students, grades
    WHERE
        min_mark <= marks
        AND   marks <= max_mark
        AND   marks <= 69
)
order by grade desc,case when grade >= 1 
                     then  name 
                     when grade < 1 
                     then  marks
                     end ;
```

But as `name` and `marks` are (presumably) different data types - string and number - that will instead get

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER

You could convert `marks` to a string, but if you do then you need to pad it so sorting the resulting string alphabetically still matches the numeric order - messy but plausible since the marks can (again, presumably - if it's a percentage?) only be up to three digits:

```
select name, grade, marks
from
(
    ...
    <the main part of your query here as a subquery, as above>
    ...
)
order by grade desc,case when grade >= 8 
                     then  name 
                     when grade < 8 
                     then  to_char(marks, 'FM000')
                     end ;
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=259ac7994eec1e6128a68ab20a313ff6) using some dummy data supplied via CTEs.

If the marks can be more than three digits then change the format mask to match the maximum possible length.

---

The `TO_CHAR('NULL')` part is also odd as that will give you the literal string "NULL" in the name column for those rows. Since you start with a string literal the `TO_CHAR()` part is pointless, just use `'NULL' AS name` directly. If you actually want it to be blank then you can just use `null AS name` and it will match the data type of the matching column expression from the first branch of the union (and will pick up its alias too). You could explicitly cast to a string type, e.g. `cast(null as varchar2(20)) AS name` but there doesn't seem to be much point.

Comment: ERROR:

order by grade desc,case when grade >= 8 
* 
ERROR at line 18: 
ORA-01785: ORDER BY item must be the number of a SELECT-list expression order by grade desc

Comment: That's your original error. Did you move your query into a subquery?

Comment: @ShanmukhaReddy - I've added a link to a demo showing this working, using some made-up data.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 forms of [CASE Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm) in SQL.

```
CASE <expression> WHEN <v1> THEN <ret1> WHEN <v2> THEN <ret2> ... END
```

The other is

```
CASE WHEN <comp1> THEN <ret1> WHEN <comp2> THEN <ret2> ... END
```

The difference is THAT IN CASE 1 you specify the value or expression to be compared once and compare it to other values or expressions, where as with variant 2, you specify a comparison expression for each WHEN.

Change the expression to

```
CASE WHEN grade >= 8 THEN name ELSE TO_CHAR(marks, '0999999999') END
```

I also formatted the marks number to a string with leading zeroes to make it sortable as text together with the name.

Comment: ERROR:
order by grade desc,(CASE WHEN grade >= 8 THEN name ELSE TO_CHAR(marks, '0999999999') END) 
* 
ERROR at line 18: 
ORA-01785: ORDER BY item must be the number of a SELECT-list expression

Comment: We have a special case, since we have UNION select. Therefore I would go with @Alex Poole's suggestion and wrap the union selects with an out select.

Comment: Would be very helpful, if you could provide the query. 
New to Oracle :)

Comment: Thank you for supporting

Comment: Alex's answer has a query doing this.