# ORA-01785: ORDER BY item must be the number of a SELECT-list expression

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a simple query that is giving me an error

> Error(2713,12): PL/SQL: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

```
SELECT XMLAgg(Case When (Select xx_info_n26 From xxsample_table Where xx_info_v1 = 'H' and xx_info_v27 = 'AR' ) > 0 Then 
      (SELECT XMLAGG(XMLCONCAT(XMLElement("tns:SprzedazWiersz",                                          
         xmlelement("tns:LpSprzedazy"      ,   rownum),
         xmlelement("tns:KodKrajuNadaniaTIN",  substr(ar_trx.tax_reg_num, 0, 2)),
         xmlelement("tns:NrKontrahenta"    ,   substr(ar_trx.tax_reg_num, 2)), 
         xmlelement("tns:NazwaKontrahenta" ,   ar_trx.cust_name),
         xmlelement("tns:DowodSprzedazy"   ,   ar_trx.trx_number),
         xmlelement("tns:DataWystawienia"  ,   TO_CHAR(ar_trx.invoice_date,'RRRR-MM-DD')),      
         Case When ar_trx.sales_date is not null Then xmlelement("tns:DataSprzedazy"    ,   TO_CHAR(ar_trx.sales_date,'RRRR-MM-DD')) END,
         -- DocumentType
         (Select  xmlelement("tns:TypDokumentu" , doctype.Document_type_code)
            from    (select distinct xx_info_n3 trx_id
                        ,   xx_info_v15         Document_type_code
                     From   xxsample_table
                     Where  xx_info_v1 = 'AR'
                     and    xx_info_v16 = 'ORA_JEPL_DOCUMENT_TYPE') doctype
            where    doctype.trx_id  = ar_trx.trx_id),  
        -- Transaction Attributes
        (Select xmlagg(xmlconcat(xmlelement(evalname(trdattr.TRANSACTION_ATTRIBUTE_CODE), 1)))
         From    ( Select distinct xx_info_v12 TRANSACTION_ATTRIBUTE_CODE
                   From   xxsample_table
                   Where  xx_info_V1 = 'AR'
                   and    xx_info_v12 <> 'tns:'
                   and    xx_info_n3 = ar_trx.trx_id 
                   UNION ALL
                   Select xx_info_v20 TRANSACTION_ATTRIBUTE_CODE
                   From   xxsample_table 
                   Where  xx_info_V1 = 'AR'
                   and    xx_info_n3 = ar_trx.trx_id 
                   and    xx_info_v20 <> 0) trdattr
        order by 
        case TRANSACTION_ATTRIBUTE_CODE 
        when 'tns:SW'       then 1
        when 'tns:EE'       THEN 2
        when 'tns:TP'       THEN 3
        when 'tns:TT_WNT'   then 4
        when 'tns:TT_D'     THEN 5
        when 'tns:MR_T'     THEN 6
        when 'tns:MR_UZ'    THEN 7
        when 'tns:I_42'     THEN 8
        when 'tns:I_63'     THEN 9
        when 'tns:B_SPV'    THEN 10
        when 'tns:B_SPV_DOSTAWA' THEN 11
        when 'tns:B_MPV_PROWIZJA' THEN 12
        when 'tns:MPP' THEN 13
        ELSE 14 END)   
        ,
        -- Kboxes
       (Select xmlagg(xmlconcat(xmlelement(evalname(ar_tax_sum.box),ar_tax_sum.amount)))
      From ( select box
                ,   sum(amount) amount
            from    (Select xx_info_v5      box
                        ,   Sum(xx_info_n1) amount
                    From    xxsample_table 
                    Where   xx_info_V1 = 'AR'
                    and     xx_info_n3 = ar_trx.trx_id
                    Group By xx_info_v5
                    UNION
                    Select  xx_info_v6      box
                         ,  Sum(xx_info_n2) amount        
                    From    xxsample_table 
                    Where   xx_info_V1 = 'AR'
                    and     xx_info_n3 = ar_trx.trx_id
                    Group By xx_info_v6)
            Where box <> 'tns:'
            group by box) ar_tax_sum
      )                                     
        ))
       )
         From ( Select distinct xx_info_n3 trx_id
                              , xx_info_v2 trx_number
                              , xx_info_d1 sales_date
                              , xx_info_d3 invoice_date
                              , xx_info_v3 cust_name
                              , xx_info_v17 cust_addr
                              , xx_info_v7  tax_reg_num
                 From xxsample_table
                 Where xx_info_v1 = 'AR'
                 Order by 3,4
              ) ar_trx
         ) End)
FROM DUAL)
```

I think this error is caused the Conditional `ORDER BY` because when i completely remove the `ORDER BY` (Lines 31-46) the query works fine. However, i'm confused as to why it would cause the error when I can run the sub-query fine on it's own:

```
Select xmlagg(xmlconcat(xmlelement(evalname(trdattr.TRANSACTION_ATTRIBUTE_CODE), 1)))
From    ( Select distinct xx_info_v12 TRANSACTION_ATTRIBUTE_CODE
           From   xxsample_table
           Where  xx_info_V1 = 'AR'
           and    xx_info_v12 <> 'tns:'
           --and      xx_info_n3 = ar_trx.trx_id 
           UNION ALL
           Select xx_info_v20 TRANSACTION_ATTRIBUTE_CODE
           From   xxsample_table 
           Where  xx_info_V1 = 'AR'
           --and      xx_info_n3 = ar_trx.trx_id 
           and    xx_info_v20 <> 0) trdattr
order by 
case TRANSACTION_ATTRIBUTE_CODE 
when 'tns:SW'       then 1
when 'tns:EE'       THEN 2
when 'tns:TP'       THEN 3
when 'tns:TT_WNT'   then 4
when 'tns:TT_D'     THEN 5
when 'tns:MR_T'     THEN 6
when 'tns:MR_UZ'    THEN 7
when 'tns:I_42'     THEN 8
when 'tns:I_63'     THEN 9
when 'tns:B_SPV'    THEN 10
when 'tns:B_SPV_DOSTAWA' THEN 11
when 'tns:B_MPV_PROWIZJA' THEN 12
when 'tns:MPP' THEN 13
ELSE 14 END
```

I also tried just the regular `ORDER BY` and it's still giving me an error.

I tried moving the `ORDER BY` into the inner most query `trdattr` and it somehow works. However, when I re-add the `CASE` statement, it's giving me the below error:

> ORA-01785: ORDER BY item must be the number of a SELECT-list
>   expression

How can i incorporate the conditional `ORDER BY` into the main query correctly?

Comment: It's rather hard to follow your code, paritcularly with its current formatting, but... you can only use an `order by` in a subquery when it's being used an an inline view (and maybe other scenarios that escape me, I'm sure I'll be corrected.). You're trying to use it in a subquery that is a column expression - it just isn't allowed there, and would have no impact on the result if it was. Why do you think you need it in its original location, and what do you expect it to do with the single result of the xmlagg?

Comment: The ORA-01785 *might* be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50933385/266304), though again it's hard to tell. A [mcve] would make it easier to see what's going on, and to potentially help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your standalone query works, but in your main query you're using that as a [scalar subquery expression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Scalar-Subquery-Expressions.html). A simplified version of your main query therefore would be:

```
select (
-- start of your standlone query
Select xmlagg(xmlconcat(xmlelement(evalname(trdattr.TRANSACTION_ATTRIBUTE_CODE), 1)))
From    ( Select distinct xx_info_v12 TRANSACTION_ATTRIBUTE_CODE
           From   xxsample_table
           Where  xx_info_V1 = 'AR'
           and    xx_info_v12 <> 'tns:'
           --and      xx_info_n3 = ar_trx.trx_id 
           UNION ALL
           Select xx_info_v20 TRANSACTION_ATTRIBUTE_CODE
           From   xxsample_table 
           Where  xx_info_V1 = 'AR'
           --and      xx_info_n3 = ar_trx.trx_id 
           and    xx_info_v20 <> 0) trdattr
order by 
case TRANSACTION_ATTRIBUTE_CODE 
when 'tns:SW'       then 1
when 'tns:EE'       THEN 2
when 'tns:TP'       THEN 3
when 'tns:TT_WNT'   then 4
when 'tns:TT_D'     THEN 5
when 'tns:MR_T'     THEN 6
when 'tns:MR_UZ'    THEN 7
when 'tns:I_42'     THEN 8
when 'tns:I_63'     THEN 9
when 'tns:B_SPV'    THEN 10
when 'tns:B_SPV_DOSTAWA' THEN 11
when 'tns:B_MPV_PROWIZJA' THEN 12
when 'tns:MPP' THEN 13
ELSE 14 END
-- end of your standalone query
)
from dual
```

... which also throws "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis".

As the docs say:

> A scalar subquery expression is a subquery that returns exactly one column value from one row.

which is what you have here - a single row with a single column which is your XMLAgg result. It is a bit pointless, and meaningless, to try to order that single row. Oracle isn't expecting to see an order-by clause at that point, it's expecting to see the closing parenthesis for the subquery expression - hence the error it throws.

When you move the order-by into the inline view, where it maybe makes more sense:

```
Select xmlagg(xmlconcat(xmlelement(evalname(trdattr.TRANSACTION_ATTRIBUTE_CODE), 1)))
From    ( Select distinct xx_info_v12 TRANSACTION_ATTRIBUTE_CODE
           From   xxsample_table
           Where  xx_info_V1 = 'AR'
           and    xx_info_v12 <> 'tns:'
           --and      xx_info_n3 = ar_trx.trx_id 
           UNION ALL
           Select xx_info_v20 TRANSACTION_ATTRIBUTE_CODE
           From   xxsample_table 
           Where  xx_info_V1 = 'AR'
           --and      xx_info_n3 = ar_trx.trx_id 
           and    xx_info_v20 <> 0
           order by 
           case TRANSACTION_ATTRIBUTE_CODE 
           when 'tns:SW'       then 1
           when 'tns:EE'       THEN 2
           when 'tns:TP'       THEN 3
           when 'tns:TT_WNT'   then 4
           when 'tns:TT_D'     THEN 5
           when 'tns:MR_T'     THEN 6
           when 'tns:MR_UZ'    THEN 7
           when 'tns:I_42'     THEN 8
           when 'tns:I_63'     THEN 9
           when 'tns:B_SPV'    THEN 10
           when 'tns:B_SPV_DOSTAWA' THEN 11
           when 'tns:B_MPV_PROWIZJA' THEN 12
           when 'tns:MPP' THEN 13
           ELSE 14 END
        ) trdattr
```

you get "ORA-01785: ORDER BY item must be the number of a SELECT-list expression", which is probably [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50933385/266304). The workaround there works here too, adding yet another level of subquery:

```
Select xmlagg(xmlconcat(xmlelement(evalname(trdattr.TRANSACTION_ATTRIBUTE_CODE), 1)))
From (
  Select *
  From    ( Select distinct xx_info_v12 TRANSACTION_ATTRIBUTE_CODE
             From   xxsample_table
             Where  xx_info_V1 = 'AR'
             and    xx_info_v12 <> 'tns:'
             --and      xx_info_n3 = ar_trx.trx_id 
             UNION ALL
             Select xx_info_v20 TRANSACTION_ATTRIBUTE_CODE
             From   xxsample_table 
             Where  xx_info_V1 = 'AR'
             --and      xx_info_n3 = ar_trx.trx_id 
             and    xx_info_v20 <> 0
          )
         order by 
         case TRANSACTION_ATTRIBUTE_CODE 
         when 'tns:SW'       then 1
         when 'tns:EE'       THEN 2
         when 'tns:TP'       THEN 3
         when 'tns:TT_WNT'   then 4
         when 'tns:TT_D'     THEN 5
         when 'tns:MR_T'     THEN 6
         when 'tns:MR_UZ'    THEN 7
         when 'tns:I_42'     THEN 8
         when 'tns:I_63'     THEN 9
         when 'tns:B_SPV'    THEN 10
         when 'tns:B_SPV_DOSTAWA' THEN 11
         when 'tns:B_MPV_PROWIZJA' THEN 12
         when 'tns:MPP' THEN 13
         ELSE 14 END
  ) trdattr
```

You can then make *that* the scalar subquery expression.

Comment: i was able to resolve it using a this very approach. I had to put it in another in-line view just for it to work. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Based on your previous question, I think you're probably trying to order the elements in the `XMLAGG()`, so you'll want to put your `order by` statement [in the xmlagg call](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions215.htm):

```
-- excerpt from your main query...
-- Transaction Attributes
(Select xmlagg(xmlconcat(xmlelement(evalname(trdattr.TRANSACTION_ATTRIBUTE_CODE), 1))
               order by 
               case TRANSACTION_ATTRIBUTE_CODE 
               when 'tns:SW'       then 1
               when 'tns:EE'       THEN 2
               when 'tns:TP'       THEN 3
               when 'tns:TT_WNT'   then 4
               when 'tns:TT_D'     THEN 5
               when 'tns:MR_T'     THEN 6
               when 'tns:MR_UZ'    THEN 7
               when 'tns:I_42'     THEN 8
               when 'tns:I_63'     THEN 9
               when 'tns:B_SPV'    THEN 10
               when 'tns:B_SPV_DOSTAWA' THEN 11
               when 'tns:B_MPV_PROWIZJA' THEN 12
               when 'tns:MPP' THEN 13
               ELSE 14 END)
 From    ( Select distinct xx_info_v12 TRANSACTION_ATTRIBUTE_CODE
           From   xxsample_table
           Where  xx_info_V1 = 'AR'
           and    xx_info_v12 <> 'tns:'
           and    xx_info_n3 = ar_trx.trx_id 
           UNION ALL
           Select xx_info_v20 TRANSACTION_ATTRIBUTE_CODE
           From   xxsample_table 
           Where  xx_info_V1 = 'AR'
           and    xx_info_n3 = ar_trx.trx_id 
           and    xx_info_v20 <> 0) trdattr),
-- Kboxes
-- continue main query
```

I can't really test it, but maybe try that.

Comment: Confirmed this today and it works! thank you! learned something new today. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach that may be useful:

```
-- SQL*Plus formatting commands
SET PAGESIZE 60
SET LINESIZE 120
COLUMN sort_key         NOPRINT
COLUMN tablespace_name  FORMAT A18
COLUMN file_name        FORMAT A40

-- two queries, each contributing to unified view of tablespaces and files
-- each using DECODE() just because it's less wordy (and still supported)
-- column aliases not required on expressions in second query in UNION, but I like using them
SELECT
DECODE(ts.tablespace_name,
'SYSTEM',   'A1',
'SYSAUX',   'A2',
'UNDOTBS1', 'B',
'USERS',    'D',
'Z') AS sort_key,
ts.tablespace_name,
f.file_name,
(f.bytes / 1024 / 1024) AS mbytes,
ts.status
FROM
dba_tablespaces ts JOIN dba_data_files f ON ts.tablespace_name = f.tablespace_name
UNION
SELECT
DECODE(ts.tablespace_name,
'TEMP',  'C',
'Z') AS sort_key,
ts.tablespace_name,
f.file_name,
(f.bytes / 1024 / 1024) AS mbytes,
ts.status
FROM
dba_tablespaces ts JOIN dba_temp_files f ON ts.tablespace_name = f.tablespace_name
ORDER BY
sort_key,
tablespace_name
;

-- results - in the order I prefer to see
TABLESPACE_NAME    FILE_NAME                                    MBYTES STATUS
------------------ ---------------------------------------- ---------- ---------
SYSTEM             C:\DEV\ORADATA\DB01\SYSTEM01.DBF               890 ONLINE
SYSAUX             C:\DEV\ORADATA\DB01\SYSAUX01.DBF               510 ONLINE
UNDOTBS1           C:\DEV\ORADATA\DB01\UNDOTBS01.DBF               60 ONLINE
TEMP               C:\DEV\ORADATA\DB01\TEMP01.DBF                  32 ONLINE
USERS              C:\DEV\ORADATA\DB01\USERS01.DBF                  5 ONLINE
MYDAT              C:\DEV\ORACLE19C\DATABASE\MYDAT01.DBF           800 ONLINE
MYIDX              C:\DEV\ORACLE19C\DATABASE\MYIDX01.DBF           800 ONLINE
```